# What is the maximum length of web socket request url?

Tags: url, websocket, jwt, request

I'm getting a 400 error when in postman when i tried to connect to a web socket because of the length of the request url.

The jwt was very large, so I quit some roles for my user to get a short one an it works

[image: Connection success]

Comment: It may depend on which web server you are using.

Comment: Related: [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/). Short answer - the HTTP specs don't define a limit, but they *recommend* implementations support *at least* 8K characters, but individual implementations can/do impose much smaller limits, typically around 2K